# In an R dataframe, how do I invert the sign of each value in a Column based upon the sign of the mean of that Column?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

In R, I have an 8 Row 4 Column dataframe.  If the mean of the entire column is less than zero, I want to invert the sign of each value in that column. If the mean of the column is greater than 0, I want to leave the data as is. I want to repeat this exercise for each of the columns. While I can do this manually for this small example, I will be expanding this to a larger data set so it would be best to code to perform this check.

Here is my data:

```
A  -0.4351361  0.3970448 -0.21396417 -0.068941849 
B  -0.3033722 -0.1301683  0.64423959  0.252927381
C  -0.2878781 -0.4148322 -0.32357299 -0.384015728 
D  -0.4800799 -0.1504586  0.34576550  0.008384542 
E  -0.4099036 -0.3702164 -0.02610686 -0.288936721 
F  -0.2903198  0.2980555 -0.01366816  0.467834269 
G  -0.3665078  0.4888855 -0.25140794 -0.137594432 
H  -0.1365168 -0.4071632 -0.50084637  0.680037368
```

Using the colMean function in R, I have obtained the following means:

```
-0.338714289 -0.036106595 -0.042445174  0.066211854
```

With Columns 1 to 3 being negative, my desired result would be to have the signs on every value in column 1,2 & 3 "flip" and to have column 4 remain the same.

```
A  0.4351361 -0.3970448   0.21396417 -0.068941849 
B  0.3033722  0.1301683  -0.64423959  0.252927381
C  0.2878781  0.4148322   0.32357299 -0.384015728 
D  0.4800799  0.1504586  -0.34576550  0.008384542 
E  0.4099036  0.3702164   0.02610686 -0.288936721 
F  0.2903198 -0.2980555   0.01366816  0.467834269 
G  0.3665078 -0.4888855   0.25140794 -0.137594432 
H  0.1365168  0.4071632   0.50084637  0.680037368
```

I was able to use an ifelse statement to get a vector of -1 and +1to reflect the direct on the Column Means

```
colMeantest = ifelse(Data.means<0,-1,1)
    colMeantest.M = as.matrix(colMeantest)
    print(colMeantest.M)
```

Which produced this:

```
> print(colMeantest.M)
    [,1]
1   -1
2   -1
3   -1
4    1
```

And this to get the transpose

```
colMeantest.Mt = t(colMeantest.M)
    print(colMeantest.Mt)

[1,]  -1  -1  -1   1
```

But with that, I could not figure out how to write a logical test using each output to get my desires result, or how to multiply them as matrices to get the desired results.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Is your first column character ('A', 'B', 'C',,..) or is it row names?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
     ~ if(mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) < 0) - 1 * x else .x))
```

---

Or with `colMeans` from `base R` (I assume the first column is not numeric based on the OP's post) - replicate the column means, get the `sign`, multiply with the original data and update the data by assignment

```
df1[-1] <- df1[-1] * sign(colMeans(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE)[col(df1[-1])])
```